# libtensorflow_framework.so.2: undefined symbol: _ZTIN6snappy4SinkE

Tags: python, tensorflow, kaggle

I am trying to import this:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
```

And when I run this code I catch follow exception:

```
ImportError: /home/rokoko/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/../../libtensorflow_framework.so.2: undefined symbol: _ZTIN6snappy4SinkE
```

How to fix that?